# How to save programatically attribute option value in Default Store View in attribute in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, attribute-value

How to save programatically attribute option value in  Default Store View in attribute in magento 1.9?

```
public function saveAttributeValueAction()
    {   
        $arg_attribute = 'ram';
        $file_handle = fopen('/var/www/dev/attributedata.csv', 'r');
        while (!feof($file_handle) ) 
        {
            $array_keyword_value[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        }
        fclose($file_handle);
        foreach ($array_keyword_value as $key1 => $value1) {
            $key_data[] = $value1[0];
        }
        $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
        $attr_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');
        $attr = $attr_model->loadByCode('catalog_product', $arg_attribute);
        foreach($key_data as $key_value)
        {   
         $option = array();
         $arg_value = trim($key_value);
         $attr_id = $attr->getAttributeId();
         $option['attribute_id'] = $attr_id;
         $option['value']['any_option_name'][0] = $arg_value;
         $setup->addAttributeOption($option);
        }
    }
```

I have to save value in attribute but not save in default store view. Please help me how to save it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is worked for me.

```
public function saveAttributeValueAction()
    {   
        $arg_attribute = 'ram';
        $file_handle = fopen('/var/www/dev/attributedata.csv', 'r');
        while (!feof($file_handle) ) 
        {
            $array_keyword_value[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        }
        fclose($file_handle);
        foreach ($array_keyword_value as $key1 => $value1) {
            $key_data[] = $value1[0];
        }
        $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
        $attr_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');
        $attr = $attr_model->loadByCode('catalog_product', $arg_attribute);
        foreach($key_data as $key_value)
        {   
         $option = array();
         $arg_value = trim($key_value);
         $attr_id = $attr->getAttributeId();
         $option['attribute_id'] = $attr_id;
         $option['value']['any_option_name'][0] = $arg_value;
         $option['value']['any_option_name'][1] = $arg_value;
         $setup->addAttributeOption($option);
        }
    }
```